# CSS to particular row in JqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a data grid where I am displaying my messages. In that if the messages are unread it should display in different CSS for i.e. the text should be bold. Is there any way to do that in JqGrid.
Please help I am new to jqGrid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the data of jqGrid are filled (for example infide of `loadComplete` event or any time later) you can use `setRowData` to change the data or CSS on a particular row (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods for the detailed description). If you want only change a row CSS without changing the data place `null` as the second parameter.

If you want know all ids from the grid you can use `getDataIDs` method. To examine data from jqGrid you can use `getRowData` or `getCell`.